# smallest n - application of Chinese remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am trying to find the smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{ 0 \}$, such that $n = 2 x^2 = 3y^3 = 5 z^5$, for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there a way to prove this by the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks to find the smallest positive integer that is simultaneously twice a square, three times a cube, and five times a fifth power.

Writing $n$ as $2^a \cdot 3^b \cdot 5^c$ and assuming that no other prime divides $n$, it follows that the following congruences must hold:

- $a$ is:

  - $\equiv 1 \pmod{2}$
  - $\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$
  - $\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$
- $b$ is:

  - $\equiv 0 \pmod{2}$
  - $\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$
  - $\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$
- $c$ is:

  - $\equiv 0 \pmod{2}$
  - $\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$
  - $\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$

The smallest values for $a$, $b$, and $c$ (which exist by the Chinese remainder theorem) are thus $15$, $10$, and $6$ respectively, so the smallest solution is $n=2^{15} \cdot 3^{10} \cdot 5^6=30,233,088,000,000$.

By the way, it happens that each prime factor of $30$ divides one less than the product of the other prime factors. A squarefree composite number with this property is called a Giuga number.

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have one question: Why is $a \equiv 1 \ ( \text{mod } 2)$ and the other terms $\equiv 0 \ ( \text{mod 3 } \text{ resp. } 5)$. The same for the $b$ and $c$ case ...

Answer (score 1):

As @MatthewDaly said it must be of form $n=2^a3^b5^c$. Although it can also has different primes, but if you want the smallest one, you should avoid to include other non necessary ones. Now suppose:
$$x=2^{a'}3^{b'}5^{c'}$$
$$y=2^{a''}3^{b''}5^{c''}$$
$$x=2^{a'''}3^{b'''}5^{c'''}$$
So we have:
$$a=2a'+1=3a''=5a''' \Longrightarrow a=30a_0+15$$
$$b=2b'=3b''+1=5b''' \Longrightarrow b=30b_0+10$$
$$c=2c'=3c''=5c'''+1 \Longrightarrow c=30a_0+6$$
So the smallest integer is $\min(n)=2^{15}3^{10}5^6$

Comment: The answer makes many claims but does not *prove* (or motivate) anything. Ok for a comment, but not for an *answer*. Further it doesn't answer the question, i.e. *by CRT*?

Comment: @BillDubuque I added some clarification, although these could be omitted to the asker as an exercise.

Comment: Alas, that minor edit does not address any of the points I raised.

Comment: The answer seems clear to me, despite leaving some basic arithmetic to the reader. Maybe it would be clearer if the equations for a,b,c were written mod30 instead of adding arbitrary multiples of 30?

Comment: The answer seems not really clear to me. Can you tell me why $a,b,c$ take these values and the implications right after ?

Comment: @lea5619 Just put $n,x,y,z$ in equation.